Autodesk ACC. Copy revit file via API
I’m using the Data Management API to automatically copy files from one folder to another using Python Code. However, I’ve discovered that when copying a Revit file, it loses its cloud properties and is no longer available for collaboration.
I'm using POST request from https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/:
url = f'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{project_id}/items'

    "data": {
        "type": "items",
        "attributes": {
            "displayName": "TEST CLOUD MODEL.rvt",
                "extension": {
                     "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
                     "version": "1.3.1",
                     "schema": {
                          "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.3.1"
                         }
            },
        "relationships": {
            "tip": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "versions",
                    "id": "1"
                }
            },
            "parent": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "folders",
                    "id": destination_folder_id
                }
            }
        }
    },

Copying is working with file types:
"type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File"
But when i change
"type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File"

to
"type": "items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel"

I receive the following error:
403
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "id": "74937b18-732c-41b8-b2df-9deea27b9b1d",
      "status": "403",
      "code": "USER_NOT_AUTHENTICATED",
      "detail": "The client_id is not whitelisted for schema 'items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel' access."
    }
  ]
}

I want to understand if it is possible to copy a Revit file (as a result, the copied file should remain collateral and can be opened from Revit)

